# Line intersection with parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Consider two non-intersecting hyperplanes $A,B \subset \mathbb{F}_q^n$ and a line $at+b$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$, and $t \in \mathbb{F}_q$ intersecting them. Is it always the case that this line intersects A and B exactly once?

This is clearly the case for $n=2$. For $n>2$, this is again clearly the case for special sets of parallel hyperplanes such as fixing any one coordinate. I imagine that since it is true for these the result essentially follows from a change of basis, but I'm having trouble writing it down explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subspace $U$ of a linear space is itself a linear space.  This means that the line spanned by any two points of $U$ must in fact be contained in $U$. Therefore, if a line $\ell$ intersects a hyperplane $U$ of $\mathrm{AG}(n,q)$, then $\ell \subset U$.

Comment: Ah, then if the line were to intersect the hyperplane U more than once it would have to lie entirely in U, thus it could not intersect a disjoint hyperplane V. I see thank you